# PostOperationCompleted in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I am following the example 1 from this link http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/246911-c%23-multi-threading-in-a-gui-environment/. But, I have to write the code in C++/CLI code instead of C#.

Basically, I declare an AsynOperation pointer like this:

```
System::ComponentModel::AsyncOperation^ op;
```

Then, in the constructor function, I need to capture the current synchronization context:

```
this->op = System::ComponentModel::AsyncOperationManager::CreateOperation(nullptr);
```

Then, in my worker thread, I have to call the PostOperationCompleted function to do the Invoke call, but I'm stuck right here after doing a lot of google search. This is my wrong line of code, and I still can not compile it:

```
this->op->PostOperationCompleted([](param1, param2) -> void { &MyClass::OnCompleted(param1, param2); }, nullptr, nullptr);
```

I looked into the MSDN but I still don't understand how to use that function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation.postoperationcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Please show me how to use the PostOperationCompleted function in C++/CLI?

Thanks all!

Comment: You cannot use lambda expressions in C++/CLI, you'll have to use a little helper function.  BackgroundWorker does all this for you.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of pain, I came up with a simple solution like following:

```
SynchronizationContext^ _sync_context;
```

Capture the sync context:

```
_sync_context = SynchronizationContext::Current;
```

Then, call the Post function like this whenever you want to fire an event:

```
_sync_context->Post(gcnew SendOrPostCallback(this, &MyClass::MyFunction), args);
```

Then, in "MyFunction", free to fire the normal C++/CLI event, it has the same synchronization context with the caller function.

Thankyou all.